# Perforce: How to revert all those files that are opened but unedited?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

Is there a way to check all the files which are opened in the p4 client and can be reverted  if we know that they are not edited.

Answer (score 7):

In P4V, on the pending changelist in question, right-click and choose *Revert Unchanged Files*.

On the command-line, you can achieve the same with `p4 revert -c CHANGELIST -a` (you can even add `-n` to preview the operation). See `p4 help revert` for more information.

Comment: You can skip the `-c CHANGELIST` if you want to check "all the files which are opened in the p4 client".